# How can i watch a video with instagram url link in json file. It gives url signature expired

Tags: json, instagram

I downloaded my instagram data which is in json file. I can view images by pasting the url link in chrome but when i paste video url link, the video does not load instead it says url signature expired..is there any way I can watch those videos? If yes please guide me in detail because I am new here

Comment: What is your real objective with watching the video?

Comment: Its just an important video that someone sent me through instagram dm. I wanted to watch that video but the chat was deleted so I downloaded my instagram data..No I have the link but when I paste it in chrome, it says URL Signature Expired. For your help I am giving an example of the link.. It starts with https://scontent-lax3-1.cdninstagram.com/ followed by a lot of letters and numbers. Is there any way I can watch that video?